# Is there a PostgreSQL equivalent of SQLite's IS operator?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, comparison-operators

[In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#binaryops), `IS` is a binary operator that behaves exactly like `=` except when one or both of the operands are `NULL`. In the case where both operands are `NULL`, the `IS` operator evaluates to `TRUE`. In the case where one operand is `NULL`, but not the other, the `IS` operand evaluates to `FALSE`.

I was looking for a similar operator in PostgreSQL, but I could not find one. Is there an equivalent of SQLite's `IS` operator in PostgreSQL? If not, what is the best/least-complicated work-around?

To clarify, `SELECT column1 IS column2 ...` is allowed in SQLite, but PostgreSQL raises a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [IS (NOT) DISTINCT FROM](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Is_distinct_from) operator.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's possible in postgresql (see dan04's). The query below would work in SQL Server and other DBMSs where that syntax isn't available.

You can simulate by doing:

```
WHERE (column1 is NULL and column2 is NULL) 
      OR column1 = column2
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Derek's answer:

In MySQL you can use the `<=>` operator to the same effect:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 <=> column2
```